# How to execute a CMD command on multiple EC2 Windows instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2, automation

Till now I was able to launch multiple EC2 Windows instance & get its parameters (password / IP) with *aws-api-tool* . 
Now I'd like to find a way to execute the selenium grid command on all those instances. Is it possible to do this with automation?
If any one can give me a sample program for this, that would be helpful.
I am running Windows server 2008 on all those instances.

Answer (score 1):

The [Amazon EC2 Systems Manager Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) can run commands on multiple Amazon EC2 instances.

It requires installation of an agent. Commands can then be run via the Management Console, [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or API calls.

Comment: Need help, can i talk u in personal?